# Entity Framework - changed generated field/column name

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a foreign key field that is generated by Entity Framework (6) at runtime. This field is related to a interfaces T field. So we end up with a field called `InterfaceFieldName_Id` - I would like to rename this (prefereably via the Fluent API) to `TypeFieldName_Id`.  I know how I can do this by adding in FK Id field to the POCO class, but I would prefer not to do that.

Is there a way to rename this generated field name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679466(v=vs.113).aspx) method to rename a *Foreign Key* that is not defined in the Model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>() 
    .HasRequired(c => c.Entity2NavProperty) 
    .WithMany(t => t.Entity1NavigationProperty) 
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("TypeFieldName_Id"));
```

If you already have a property in your model that represent the FK and it was renamed by EF in your DB, then you should check your relationship.Code First falls back to automatically introducing one in the database in case the foreign key property hasn't been discovered by convention, and none is configured. The foreign key property will be discovered by convention if it is named `[Target Type Key Name]`, `[Target Type Name] + [Target Type Key Name]`, or `[Navigation Property Name] + [Target Type Key Name]`.
Now to configure explicitly what is the FK property you want to use, you can can do the following:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>() 
    .HasRequired(c => c.Entity2NavProperty) 
    .WithMany(t => t.Entity1NavigationProperty)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TypeFieldName);
```

And if you want to use a different name for `TypeFieldName` in your DB, then you can also do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>().Property(d=>d.TypeFieldName).HasColumnName("TypeFieldName_Id")
```

Comment: The first part was exactly what I was looking for. I thought that mapping command wound do something completely different so never tried it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the column name fluently:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>() 
         .HasRequired(c => c.InterfaceFieldName) 
         .WithMany(d => d.YourColumnName) 
         .HasForeignKey(c => c.FieldName);
```

Comment: Thanks, I probably didn't write my question very clearly. But I want to rename the field that is stored in the database. Way everything in linked together is fine.